# How to specify a default value for a boolean field using MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

How can you specify a `defaultValue` when mapping a DTO using MapStruct? The following constructs did not work

```
@Mapping(target = "used", defaultValue = "0")
MyDTO toDto(MyEntity entity);

@Mapping(target = "used", defaultValue = "false")
MyDTO toDto(MyEntity entity);
```

The documentation shows examples for all types except booleans

Comment: What does it didn't work mean? How didnthe generated code look like? What did you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 25):

To be able to use `defaultValue`, you must specify a `source`. If the `source` is null then it will use the `defaultValue` defined.

To always assign a specific value to the target, in your case zero or false, you should then use `constant` instead.

More info on [Default values and constants](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#default-values-and-constants)

Comment: Using `constant` directive worked for me. MapStruct is able to convert to actual type specified as a String value. e.g. `used` is assigned as false if it is of type `boolean`.

```
@Mapping(target = "used", constant = "false")
MyDTO toDto(MyEntity entity);
```